# Unauthorized payment error in paypal while using LIVE credentials

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal REST API for payments.All was working fine with sandbox credentials but when I switched to LIVE credentials.It is giving errors like this :
Request to paypal API :

```
{
    "body": {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "credit_card",
            "funding_instruments": [
                {
                    "credit_card_token": {
                        "credit_card_id": "CARD-7314506536077511MK7WL121",
                        "payer_id": "57ecbbed656c78519a28382c"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": 10
                },
                "description": "Payment taken from customer Neha for booking #SR1032 and to be send to SP Neha and SP paypal Id hello@y.bom"
            }
        ]
    },
    "header": {
        "x-pp-ads-performed": "false",
        "content-length": "374",
        "pp_remote_addr": "54.244.2.156",
        "paypal-request-id": "2afb7a93-0cc2-4ab2-b216-45b8de908f9f",
        "pp_geo_loc": "US",
        "x-pp-silover": "name=LIVE3.API.1&silo_version=880&app=platformapiserv&TIME=2734681175&HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR=",
        "host": "api.paypal.com",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "client-auth": "No cert",
        "connection": "close",
        "x-pp-idempotencyid": "eabb84d3ef438_1475149730",
        "x-slr-orig-script_uri": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/",
        "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp": "platformapiserv",
        "x-pp-corrid": "eabb84d3ef438",
        "user-agent": "PayPalSDK/PayPal-node-SDK 1.6.9 (node v4.5.0-x64-linux; OpenSSL 1.0.2h)",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9T1G"
    },
    "additional_properties":
```

Response from paypal server

```
 {
    "status": 401,
    "duration_time": 49,
    "body": {
        "message": "Unauthorized payment.",
        "debug_id": "eabb84d3ef438",
        "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT",
        "name": "UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT"
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "header": {
        "Content-Length": "191",
        "Content-Language": "*",
        "CORRELATION-ID": "eabb84d3ef438",
        "Date": "Thu, 29 Sep 2016 11:48:50 GMT",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Paypal-Debug-Id": "eabb84d3ef438",
        "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host=dcg12javapapi7866.dcg12.slc.paypalinc.com;threadId=704",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this working? What was the issue?

Comment: There was some issue with paypal account..we have to enable direct payments from the dashboard,which is only available in US.